# Submenu items not showing in full browser (CSS)

Tags: css, menuitem, submenu

My submenu disappeared all the sudden and doesn't show anymore when I hover over the menu item. I checked the menu section on my WP dashboard and it's there and assigned to show. The submenu still show on mobile device but on full browser the submenu items stopped showing up. I deactivated all the plugins to check if there is a conflict but the event doesn't appear to be plugin related. This is more of a CSS problem that I'm having.

Here's my website: http://www.apcm.ca 
My  CSS : http://www.apcm.ca/wp-content/themes/apcm/css/style.css?ver=4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

You'll notice that your `#header` is set to `overflow:visible` in mobile, and that if you switch back to desktop resolution, the submenu will start working. So all you need to do is add `overflow: visible` to the `#header` in all resolutions.

Comment: Kudos!!! I just replaced overflow:hidden by overflow:visible et Voila. You are amazing. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm glad it worked. Can you mark this as answered? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

change `overflow:hidden` to `overflow:visible` for the `section#header`